# THE SUBMIT BUTTON

Tags: submit

Udemy: Bootcamp course: section: 8 Lecture: 122: SAVING TO THE DATABSE: In the "Contact Us" page I filled in the info, Name: test1, Email: test1@example.com, Comments: test1, as a test, pressed submit, but the button do not submit the info and gives no error message. Where am I going wrong? Any expert advice? Here is my code:

```
    class ContactsController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @contact = Contact.new
      end

      def create
        @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

         if @contact.save
           flash[:success] = 'Message sent.'
           redirect_to new_contact_path
         else
           flash[:danger] = 'Error occured, message has not been sent.'
           redirect_to new_contact_path 
         end
      end
   end
     private
     def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
     end

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         <div class="well"
           <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
             <div class="form-group">
               <%= f.label :name %>
               <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
               <%= f.label :email %>
               <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
             </div>

             <div class="form-group">
               <%= f.label :comments %>
               <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
             </div>
           <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
        <% end %>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not a rails expert but you can try `<%= form_for(@contact, :method => :get) do |f| %>` that should get it to work.

In your `contact.rb` model type the following

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Comment: angkiki - I allied your suggested code, but I get this error:

Comment: @ImranAli I applied your solution with the migration file and it worked perfectly. Now I have a problem, my submit button does not submit and I get no messages. When I enter, bundle exec rails c and Contact.all in the terminal no submit info is displayed. I am stuck, your expert advice.

Comment: I enter info in the fields in the Contact Us page, click the submit button and nothing get submitted nor do any messages, 'Message sent' or 'Error' are indicated. I applied your suggestion, still I get an error message. When I enter bundle exec rails c and Contact.all in the terminal, no entries are indicated.

Comment: Can you show your model.rb code? You have a contact table defined right? Also when you tried whats the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: I have no models.rb, but here is the code in my db/migrate: class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :comments
      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

Comment: You need to have a model contact.rb too (note that its model not modelS for all model name ). I'll add the code to my original answer and you try that out.

Comment: No info is saved to the database, submit button do not submit, no error message. Here is the code in my contacts.rb file: class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true
end

Comment: Entered info in the form field in the Contact Us page as a test - name: Theo; email: ntgoosen@gmail.com, comments: Dev Match Web, clicked Submit and this info indicated in the address bar: /contacts?utf8=✓&contact[name]=Theo contact[email]=ntgoosen%40gmail.com&contact[comments]=Dev+Match+Web&commit=Submit and the following error message: missing template contacts/index, application/index with {:locale => [en], :formats => [:html], :variants =>[], :handlers => [:erb, :builder, :raw, : ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.  This means the Submit button submits, but missing template How can this fixed?

Comment: It means your view is missing. I can't tell you how to fix it without seeing your routes. Do a simple google search to try and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Here is the code in the routes.rb file: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts
  get '/about' => 'pages#about'
  root 'pages#home'

Comment: it appears you do not have a route to where you are redirecting to after you save your contact form. In routes.rb add your route in for wherever it is you are redirecting to after you save and create the relevant views for it.

Comment: It's a pitty I do not have your email then I could have supplied you with my complete code in all the files and folders including screenshots of the problem I'm encouter.

Comment: Its a very simple problem to solve. Go to guides.rubyonrails.org and read through the relevant topics. Its better to try solving the problem on your own rather than having people provide you with the answer right away. You would learn much faster too. Its quite apparent that you lack a fundamental understanding of the MVC concept in rails. I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct though. Cheers

Comment: The problem of saving to the database had been sloved, making simple adjustments in the application.html.erb and controller.rb folders.